# Accessor function inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js

Can you put an accessor function inside a function. For example, something like this:

```
    function filterByCounty(data, county) {
    xValue: function (d){ return d.element; },
    yValue: function (d){ return d.value; }
    return data.filter(function (d){
      return d.County === county;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: your xValue and yValue things don't really make sense there, but everything else does

Comment: What is your code block trying to accomplish? The `xValue` and `yValue` don't do anything in that block.

Comment: I did test it and it doesn't do what I am trying to achieve - What I want it to do is, take in an array (data) and return the d.element -> xValue and the d.value ->yValue. I just don't know how accessor functions work?

Answer (score -1):

You can define accessors on `xValue` and `yValue` like that:

```js
function filterByCounty(data, county) {
  // `this` refers to the function
  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    xValue: {
      get: () => {
        return d => d.element;
      }
    },
    yValue: {
      get: () => {
        return d => d.value;
      }
    }
  });
  return data.filter(d => {
    return d.County === county;
  });
}
```